# Appcelerator doesn't work with genymotion

Tags: appcelerator, genymotion

I cannot get appcelrator to work with Genymotion.

Everytime i "run" - that is, hit the green run button in the top-left - i get [ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "192.168.25.101:5555"
[ERROR] :  Error: device not found

This isn't useful nor is it helpful.

I can *manually* drag the created .apk file into genymotion and it will run it (although, irritatinly, it immediately crashes as I'm upgrading an old app to whatever new style appcelerator have decided on).

All the posts on this are from 2014 and not very useful - I also cannot get appcelerator running genymotion on a blank new project.

I installed genymotion to a different directory, but appcelerator seems to find it and start it - i can see genymotion start up.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have seen the Appcelerator emulator wait startup timeout before Appcelerator can send the APK. What I have done is start the emulator first independent of the 'run' command in Appcelerator, then select the emulator from Appcelerator and then Run. If the emulator has started, then it will send it without having to drag/drop the apk manually.